# Date format is changing in SQL developer

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to import the excel data into oracle database through SQL developer. I have change the date format in excel to the standard oracle format(DD_MON_YYYY HH:MI:SS AM). But while importing in SQL developer this date format is not reflecting, it is giving original date format as there in excel before I changed the format.  How can I change the format?

Excel data:

[image: Excel data screen shot]

In SQL developer:

[image: SQL DEVELOPER SCREEN SHOT]

Answer (score 0):

As for my knowledge, your import is all right. Importance of the date format is to identify the date field as a date field when you are importing the data to database. After the import, database keep the date values in a default date format. So when you are retrieving the data, you have to specify the date format in your query to get what you want. In other words, use a query to get the data in the database.

Ex:

```
  select  to_date(date_field,'DD_MON_YYYY')
  from    table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [change the data format in the SQL Developer preferences](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/02/oracle-date-datatype-should-be-datetime-datatype/), tools > preferences > database > NLS

This will set the default format for displaying dates. You can always get it exactly the way you want for your queries by doing what +Asanga shows.